# Select posts inner join category slug

Tags: mysql, join

```
╔═════════════╦════════════╗
║    posts    ║ categories ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╣
║ id          ║ id         ║
║ title       ║ name       ║
║ slug        ║ slug       ║
║ content     ║            ║
║ category_id ║            ║
╚═════════════╩════════════╝
```

Given the `slug` of a category, I want to select all posts from that category. The posts are linked with `category_id` -> `id` of category.

```
SELECT `posts.title` 
FROM `categories` 
INNER JOIN `posts` 
ON `posts`.`division` = "1"
WHERE `category_slug` = "$category_slug"
```

It's giving me a `Unknown column 'posts.title' in 'field list'` though. How do I select all posts given the slug of the category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want

```
SELECT `posts`.`title`
```

instead of

```
SELECT `posts.title`
```

Comment: It's getting all posts though, not the posts on that category.

Comment: well I'm not sure what your schema actually looks like, since it doesn't seem to match the picture you drew. But perhaps you want something like `ON posts.category_id = categories.id`?

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
SELECT `posts`.`title`
```